# Derivative of Mittag-Leffler type function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, special-functions, monotone-functions

I am working on the following function for a fixed $0<\nu<1$.
$$
f(t) = E_\nu (-t^\nu) = \sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{t^{n \nu}}{\Gamma(n\nu +1)}
$$
where $E_\nu(\cdot)$ is a [Mittag-Leffler function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function)

I want to show that

> $f(t) = E_\nu (-t^\nu)$ is decreasing for $t>0$.

I have tried the usual idea: Showing the derivative is negative. However the derivative function which is
$$
f'(t) = \frac{d}{dt}E_\nu (-t^\nu) = \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{t^{n \nu-1}}{\Gamma(n\nu)}
$$
also hard to deal with. I have tried separating the cases $0<t<1$ and $t >1$. I believe for large $t$ the derivative function should be "much more negative". I couldn't prove that either.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the integral representation for $0<\nu<1$ (e.g. see this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.0161 , equation 2.14)
$$
f(t)=E_\nu (-t^\nu) = \sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{t^{n \nu}}{\Gamma(n\nu +1)}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}\frac{x^{\nu-1} \sin (\pi  \nu)}{x^{2 \nu}+2 x^\nu \cos (\pi  \nu)+1}dx
$$
we immdediately see that $f(t)$ is decreasing for $t>0$.

Comment: This paper is great. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your answer!